# How to output json array objects in a div

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am trying to get data from an api and would like to display each json array object in a div or put 2 line breaks. My code just displays all the array objects dawn the page but I want that every object data separated for good readability. How can i adjust my code so that I have line breaks after every objs content?

Here is my json:

```
{
"players": [
    {
        "name": "Marcos Alonso",
        "position": "Left-Back",
    },
    {
        "name": "Marco van Ginkel",
        "position": "Central Midfield",
    }
articles": [
    {
        "author": "Stephen Walter",
        "url": "http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/04/15/disruptive-stag-party-revellers-thrown-plane-manchester-airport/",
    },
    {
        "author": "TMG",
        "url": "http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/04/15/north-korea-marks-anniversary-military-parade-pyongyang-pictures/",
    }],

...........
......
}
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#getstuff').click(function () {
        var requestdata = $('#choi').val();
        var result = $('#resultdiv');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost/project/v1/api/webservice',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var html = '';
                var array = data[requestdata];
                if (array) {
                    $.each(array, function (i) {
                        $.each(array[i], function (key, value) {
                            html += ('<li>' + key + ': ' + value + '</li>');
                        });
                        result.html(html);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If I search with the "players", I want something like this. Space btw objs;

```
name    :  Marcos Alonso
Position:  Left-Back

name    :  Marco van Ginkel
Position:  Central Midfield
```

But when I run my code I was gething:

```
name    :  Marcos Alonso
Position:  Left-Back  
name    :  Marco van Ginkel
Position:  Central Midfield
```

I would need help on how to put line break btw each objs content or put each objs contents in a div. Whichever is better. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<br>` way:

```
$(function () {
    $('#getstuff').click(function () {
        var requestdata = $('#choi').val();
        var result = $('#resultdiv');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost/project/v1/api/webservice',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var html = '';
                var array = data[requestdata];
                if (array) {
                    $.each(array, function (i) {
                        $.each(array[i], function (key, value) {
                            html += ('<li>' + key + ': ' + value + '</li>');
                        });
                        html += '<br><br>'; // this is where to add it
                        result.html(html);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And the `<div>` way, which would be preferred (also because it wraps the list items in a list element):

```
$(function () {
    $('#getstuff').click(function () {
        var requestdata = $('#choi').val();
        var result = $('#resultdiv');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost/project/v1/api/webservice',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var html = '';
                var array = data[requestdata];
                if (array) {
                    $.each(array, function (i) {
                        html += '<div><ul>';
                        $.each(array[i], function (key, value) {
                            html += ('<li>' + key + ': ' + value + '</li>');
                        });
                        html += '</ul></div>';
                        result.html(html);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Addey no problem, feel free to upvote and/or accept my answer.